# Every monoid admits a surjection from a free monoid?

Tags: category-theory

How can I show that every monoid $M$ admits a surjection from a free monoid $F(X) \rightarrow M$ ?

Comment: Have you tried taking the free monoid on M itself?

Comment: Universal properties are your friend (for a lifetime).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $X$ is called an alphabet. You can take $M$ itself as alphabet and then the morphism $\mu : F(M)\rightarrow M$ is just the multiplication.

To be more specific, the structure of monoid is the data of a triplet $(M,*,1_M)$ where

- $M$ is a set

  $*$ is an associative internal law in $M$,

  $1_M$ is the neutral

The elements of $F(M)$ are *strings* $m_1.m_2.\cdots .m_k$ where the $m_i\in M$, then
$$
\mu(m_1.m_2.\cdots .m_k)=m_1*m_2*\cdots *m_k
$$
the stars standing for the multiplication inside the monoid $M$.

Comment: Of course this is the right answer, but should we be answering such non-research-level questions on MO?

Comment: Also you can take for X a generating set for M. Since the algebra has only one binary operation (and one constant operation), the generating set can be significantly smaller than the underlying set for M only if the underlying set is countable.  Gerhard "This Is Basic General Algebra" Paseman, 2016.11.25.

Comment: Someone should answer the questions. Someone else should migrate the question.  Those who migrate should edit the post to indicate why the migration occurred.  Gerhard "We Can Work Outside MathOverflow" Paseman, 2016.11.25.

Comment: what do you mean by "the stars standing for the multiplication inside the monoid M" ?

Comment: Just, I note $(M,*,1_M)$ the monoid. See the amended answer.

Comment: @LSpice I am fine with the migration (just wanted to help the student).